Azure Front Door URL rewrite to lowercase and segment url_path
We have a website https://www.example.com/detail/nameXXX/abcDEF, and we want to redirect to https://www.example.com/detail/abcdef. The rules are blow:

drop the second segment(nameXXX) in url_path.
lowercase the last segment in url_path.

We can use {url_path:seg#} to segment the url_path and use {url_path.tolower} to lowercase the url_path, but how to use one operation to segment and lowercase the url_path??
We tried to use {url_path:seg#.tolower}, {url_path:seg#}.tolower and {{url_path:seg#}}.tolower. All those are useless.


Azure Front Door URL rewrite to lowercase and segment url_path.

You can create a ruleset in Azure Front Door as shown below to drop the second segment and lowercase the last segment in the url path

Configure the destination path as below
/{url_path:seg0}/{url_path:seg2:99}

After creating the rule, it successfully drops the second segment (nameXXX) in url_path as shown below


Is there a way to lowercase and segment the URL path in one rule? That is what I concern.

Hi @user26214416, It is not possible to combine lowercasing and segmentation into a single rule.

Got it, thanks for your help.
